# How do I detect how to escape spaces in a path

Tags: windows, ruby, cygwin

In Cygwin a space in a path has to be escaped with a backslash
Not true in Windows, put the whole path in a quote

Is there a way to convert to this automatically in Ruby?

Otherwise, how in Ruby do I detect if I am running with Windows or Cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rant.rubyforge.org/

```
sys.escape("foo bar")
# gives on Windows: '"foo bar"'
# other systems: 'foo\ bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting paths in Cygwin ought to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to detect the platform at least - the RUBY_PLATFORM constant defines that.